# Getting the url parameters in an ejs template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to create an ejs conditional based on a URL parameter, for example, if the test parameter exists at localhost:3000/page?test, then show a div, else dont show it.

My ejs template looks something like:

```
<% include header %>
<div class="row">
<%if (title !== "homepage") {%>
<%= title %>
  <div>
    <% include nav %>
  </div>
<%}%>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
<% include footer %>
```

Is there a way to access the URL parameters directly from the ejs file? For example, the <%= title %> works fine, is there something like <%= req.query %>?

I am also using express.

Answer (score 19):

You can pass it easily as an object in the second argument to `render()`

```
app.get('/someurl', function(req, res, next) {
   res.render('filename', {query : req.query});
});
```

You can also use the `locals` variable

```
app.get('/someurl', function(req, res, next) {
   res.locals.query = req.query;
   res.render('filename');
});
```

which is very useful when used with a general route that runs before all the other routes, making the variable available in all the following routes

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.locals.query = req.query;
   res.locals.url   = req.originalUrl;

   next();
});
```

and it's available in the file you're rendering as `query` etc

```
<% if (query == "something") { %>
    <div id="crazy_shit">
        <a href="<%- url -%>">Here</a>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

As a sidenote, if `query` for some reason isn't defined, you'll get an error in EJS for using an undefined variable, which can be annoying.

I usually solve this by using an object instead, as checking object properties does not trigger errors, and it's easy to make sure the object always has an initial value at the top of each EJS template.
It's done like this in the routes

```
app.user(function(req, res, next) {
   res.locals.stuff = {
       query : req.query,
       url   : req.originalUrl
   }

   next();
});
```

And then in the template

```
<% stuff = typeof stuff !== 'object' ? {} : stuff %>

// later on

<% if ( stuff.query == "something") { %>//does not throw error if property not defined
    <div id="crazy_shit"></div>         
<% } %>
```

which even if `stuff.query` is defined, the condition just fail and it doesn't throw an error like it would if `stuff` itself, or any other variable, wasn't defined.

Comment: Also, you can have a custom middleware before the routing middleware like the following: `app.use(function (req, res, next) {res.locals.some_var='var';next();});`. That way the var will be available in all views. Useful to pass `req` data like url path for navigation.

Answer (score 11):

```
<%= req.query.paramName %>
```

Works for me where `paramName` is the name of your URL query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

just the send the stuff in the form of query which can be easily retrieved

```
app.get('/category', function(req, res) {
  var string = stuff
  res.redirect('/?valid=' + string);
});
```

In the ejs template you can directly use parameter name

```
<% var k = valid %>
```