# Fetching query string in an ejs template

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am very to nodeJS, I have the following file as `router.js`:

```
exports.redirectlogin = function ( req, res, next ) {
    // some logic
    res.redirect( '/login ', {redirecturl: req.originalUrl} );
};
```

I am passing the `req.originalUrl` as a query string. Now I want to access that in `login.ejs` file. I tried the following ways, but none of them worked:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 log-in margin-20">Log In</div>
    <form class="margin-20" method="POST" action="/login">
        // some code
        <input name="redirecturl1" type="hidden" value="<%= redirecturl %>" />
        <input name="redirecturt2" type="hidden" value=<%= redirecturl %> />
        <input name="redirecturl3" type="hidden" value=<% redirecturl %> />
        // some code
    </form>
</div>
```

But I am getting an error as `redirecturl` is not defined  in all these cases. What is the correct way to fetch it in ejs file?

Comment: Can you refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130960/getting-the-url-parameters-in-an-ejs-template/33083106

Comment: yes I referred this one. But it didn't work. I didn't want to use locals

Comment: If you are using `ExpressJS` then you are using wrong syntax, you may refer https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a res.redirect, this sends the user to a new URL, it does not do any template building. In this case you will need to add code to your `/login` route to pull out the `redirecturl` from the `req` object and then push it into the template within your `/login`'s `res.render` call. For example inside `app.get('login'...);`

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  const redirectUrl = req.params.redirecturl;

  return res.render('pages/login', {redirecturl: redirectUrl });
});
```

Comment: this didn't work, I am still getting an error in login.ejs : 
redirecturl is not defined

Comment: Please provide some more information as to why this didn't work? I've tried this locally and it works just fine, perhaps I haven't explained it well enough.

Comment: Found the issue. Thanks for this answer